# Attach a view to a specific node

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm looking for a module that makes it possible to attach an existing view to a specific node. I've looked at [eva](http://drupal.org/project/eva), but it seems only to allow connecting a view to all entities of a specific content-type. I wrote my own module, that can do this, and it works, but I would like to use a module that is well tested and maintained. Does anyone have any suggestions?

*** EDIT ***

I have installed the `views reference` module and this seems to be what I want, but when I do `print_r($content)` in my `node--type.tpl.php` file, the only thing related to this field is the following:

```
[field_attached_view] => Array (
                        [und] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                               [view_id] => products_view:first_display
                               [arguments] => sample/all/jeans
                             )
                         )
                     )
```

I have managed to load and display the view by something like this:

```
  $view_id = $node->field_attached_view[$node->language][0]['view_id'];
  $parts = explode(':',$view_id);

  $args = explode('/',$node->field_attached_view[$node->language][0]['arguments']);
  $view = views_get_view($parts[0]);
  $view->set_display($parts[1]);
  $view->set_arguments($args);
  $view->execute();
  echo $view->render();
```

But, there must be a cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very strange because normally your view should return some results .. Try to do this: hide($content['field_attached_view']); print render($content);  print render($content['field_attached_view']);

Comment: @nourcy - Tried that and still the view isn't displayed=(

Comment: Ok a last thing and if it still doesn't work I don't know: Try to remove your argument to see all results of your view

Comment: @nourcy - Tried to remove the arguments completly, with no luck. Very strange, if you look at my above code I use the supplied arguments and the machine_name & display_name to load the view and then everything works, so it seems like the call to `render` doesn't do anything with the data in `field_attached_view`.

Comment: And if you inspect your html with firebug or something there is nothing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [View reference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module.

> Defines a field type *View reference* which creates a relationship to a Views display and allows the view to be displayed as the content of the field.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, I can now attach a view from within my nodes edit form, but then in my `node--type.tpl.php` file how do I render the view?

Comment: View reference is a field so you can configure where you want to see your view. For theaming your view, use the normal way in your view configuration.

Comment: I have a view that displays fine when going to it's normal path. Now I have connected this view to one of my nodes, but it doesn't show up when going to the nodes url? In the nodes template I use `echo render($content);` to display it's output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to check if: your view returns some results ; your reference field is displayed in your content type display (admin/structure/types/manage/page/display). try to look what you have in your $content before rendering with a dpm for example (Devel module) and tell us after

Comment: I have updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a view as a block. In the block settings you can configure it to display it on "Only the listed pages" and display in the region you want.

Comment: Yes, that would work I guess, but I don't want editors to have to go in en editing the view each time they would like to connect a view to a specific node. I don't think I would like editors touching the views at all. They should only have the choice to attach a view from within the nodes edit form or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context):

1. Create a Block Display in your View.
2. Create a new context.
3. Use the specific node path as a Rule for that Context. Example: node/123
4. "Drag & Drop" the Block Display you created in step #1 to one of the regions available in your node page.

You could also do more complex things with Views, such as attaching a View to all the nodes of a particular content type when a user with a certain role is active, just to name an example. As a plus, Contexts are exportable, and you can package and deploy them to your production sites using [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features). If you decide to use Context you will be using a method widely used by the larger Drupal community.

Comment: I will try this in the morning, thank you very much.