# Using views to display KML of each node in respective maps for each node

Tags: views, javascript, location

I have been using [OpenLayers](https://drupal.org/project/openlayers) and [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) to try display the custom data layer (KML polygon) on the. First of all I havent been successful at it despite trying out many mays. Also I realized that the views approach discussed almost everywhere would show the custom maps on a 'new' Page or a 'new' block. But what I want is to show the map with the KML data layer right at each node.

Is this ever possible using Views (Data layer) + Openlayer + geofield in first case?

If so, how do I configure the geofield's map which is displayed in each node?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your question is how to attach a view to a node.
You can check out the [EVA](https://drupal.org/project/eva) module:

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views
>   display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the
>   content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the
>   profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are
>   all examples of entity content.

or this other question: [Attach a view to a specific node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/attach-a-view-to-a-specific-node)

Comment: Could you expand this a little bit to explain how this would work with these modules?